# What can be the security related cons associated with phonegap or Apache cordova and how can we get our hybrid app secured from threats?

Tags: html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, code-security

The security challenges are often faced while developing an application. Therefore, the information related to security of the application must be known to the developers.